# My program sometime freeze when i type high score text field?

Tags: java, jtextfield, keyevent

I am making a game that work with swing components (only for submitting high scores) but sometimes when I  type things freeze; I don't know why and it's hard to debug.

So, I had to do this

```
create class SubmitHighScore(ScreenManager, int forScore)
implement KeyListener
```

I disabled swing to draw itself with the class that I created, called NullRepaintManager. I did this so I can draw without flicker

This is the implemented method that I filled

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //e.consume();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
        highScore.addScore(new Score(highScoreTextField.getText(),score));
        exit.tap();
    }
    //e.consume();

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    //filter High Score text. Only A-Z and a-z otherwhise will ignore
    highScoreTextField.setText(filter(highScoreTextField.getText()));
    //e.consume();
}
```

This is a simple name that will be submitted when a player presses the ENTER key, but it freezes sometimes. I have tried using setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false) and called e.consume (which makes my textfield not fill up when I called consume)

How do I fix this?

Is there another way to submit high scores? Note that I decorate high scores with bg and frame so it look just like another game.

Comment: Why are you using a KeyListener for the enter key?  If a JTextField, you would use an ActionListener instead. Otherwise, I think that you have to provide a lot more information and code, and quite possibly a small compilable and runnable program, an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: And how do you "disable Swing"? Note that an intermittent error suggests a Swing threading issue, that you're trying to make Swing calls off of the main Swing thread, the EDT (event dispatch thread)

Comment: The answer is I don't know how to use ActionListener. I will try. Disable Swing? I'm not disable swing just only to draw sametime with my pic and sprite. If not it will flicker.

Comment: `"I'm not disable swing just only to draw sometime..."` -- Again, **how** are you disabling it when you do this? Again, I think that we need more information, possibly more code, and optimally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  These things would likely help us help you, so whether you do this or not is up to you and depends on how much you need our help.

Comment: Ah.... I'm confuse... i'll update my question tomorrow. I'm tired. Sorry about my english :(( Btw thx alot Hovercarft Full Of Eels. :D

Comment: Also, double-check that all the code you run inside your handlers terminates promptly.  If for example, highscore.addScore or the Score constructor doesn't return, that could cause a freeze.

Comment: Is this for mobile development?